# Team City build of orchard CMS failing

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, orchardcms

I am new to Orchard and MVC 3. Now, am trying to build my solution under Team City. But it is not building successfully.

I had downloaded the whole source from orchard's website. The directory structure is

OrchardSite (Root Folder)
->Lib (Root's Sub Folder)
->Src (Root's Sub Folder)

Both these folders are a part of my repo.

The build in Team City fails and complains of not being able to find any dependencies.
A snapshot of the error log :

```
[12:09:09]: Orchard\Orchard.Framework.csproj (13s)
[12:09:10]: [Orchard\Orchard.Framework.csproj] CoreCompile (12s)
[12:09:10]: [CoreCompile] Csc (12s)
[12:09:21]: [Csc] ContentManagement\ContentItemBehavior.cs(2, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClaySharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[12:09:21]: [Csc] ContentManagement\ContentItemBehavior.cs(5, 40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClayBehavior' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[12:09:21]: [Csc] ContentManagement\DefaultContentDisplay.cs(5, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClaySharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[12:09:21]: [Csc] ContentManagement\IContentBehavior.cs(1, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClaySharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Not sure what needs to be done. Can someone please help me out?

P.S. I don't want to make this post too long - so, if there is anything that you need to know and I have missed out, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Team City as our continuous integration. You can probably take a peek at our configuration: http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project143&tab=projectOverview

Here is a copy of our settings:

General Settings
Name: * 
Description:
Build number format:   *
Format may include '{0}' as a placeholder for build counter value, for example 1.{0}. It may also contain a reference to any available parameter, for example, VCS revision number: %build.vcs.number.*%.
Note: maximum length of a build number after all substitutions is 256 characters.

Build counter: *     Reset counter
Artifact paths:
 Edit artifact paths:

Hide
New line or comma separated paths to build artifacts. Support ant-style wildcards like dir/**/*.zip and target directories like *.zip => winFiles,unix/distro.tgz => linuxFiles, where winFiles and linuxFiles are target directories.
Fail build if:
 build process exit code is not zero
 at least one test failed
 an error message is logged by build runner
 it runs longer than   minutes 
 an out of memory or crash is detected (Java only)
Build options:   enable hanging builds detection 
 enable status widget
Limit the number of simultaneously running builds (0 - unlimited)

Checkout Settings
VCS checkout mode:
Checkout directory:
Leave blank to use default checkout directory on an agent.

Clean all files before build:
VCS Labeling
VCS labeling mode:       Do not label 
 Successful only 
 Always 
Labeling pattern:
Choose VCS roots to label:   Orchard Mercurial (CodePlex) (1.x)

Build Step
Runner type:
Runner for MSBuild files
Step name:
You can specify build step name to distinguish it from other steps.
Build file path: *
Specified path should be relative to the checkout directory.

Working directory:
Optional, specify if differs from the checkout directory.

MSBuild version:
MSBuild ToolsVersion:
Run platform:
Targets:
Enter targets separated by space or semicolon.

Command line parameters:
Enter additional command line parameters to MSBuild.exe.

Reduce test failure feedback time:   Run recently failed tests first
.NET Coverage
.NET Coverage tool:

Build Trigger   Parameters Description
VCS Trigger  Quiet period: 300 seconds (default)

Comment: Hi @Bertand, thank you for giving such a detailed answer. My setting is just like that..I was wondering if there was something else that needs to be done as the compilation was complaining that it couldn't find the DLLs in the Lib folder. Is that how your directory structure is as well?

Comment: I'm as puzzled as you are: the clay dll comes in the lib directory that is at the root of the source code repository. Can you check on the CI server that you have the lib directory with clay in it and that the path from the project is correctly pointing there?

Comment: It finally compiled! Initially, when I had set up the configuration, I had set the build step - Runner Type to Visual Studio (sln). Changed it to MSBuild later. For some reason, when I passed the relative folder path to Orchard.csproj file, as a command line parameter, it was complaining. So, moved it to the Build File Path section instead and whoa! It compiled! Thanks heaps! One question though - how do I go about building artifacts (specifying the location they should be put in)?

Comment: Here are the artifact paths:artifacts/**/*.zip
artifacts/**/*.nupkg

Comment: But how do I go about mentioning the artifacts path in the TeamCity build? I tried passing /T:Package as a command line parameter but the build complains that such a build target doesn't exist. Do I have to change the project's Package/Publish Web properties?

Comment: The build step that builds artifacts has the target "Build"

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I still don't understand the process may be. I tried building the Orchard.csproj using msbuild and mentioned target as build (/t:build), but still I could not see any artifacts generated. The solution builds just as fine with no errors. Do I need to change some settings first?

Comment: That didn't work either. On My local machine, it compiled but didn't create the artifacts. When I try to build the solution via team City, it doesn't even build when I assign 'Package' as target and complains that such a target doesn't exist.

Comment: Where did you look for the artifacts?

Comment: Looked under /Orchard.Web folder and /Tools/Orchard folder.

Comment: Look at the root of your clone, there should be an artifacts folder.

Comment: Checked a few times...couldn't find it anywhere :( Even when I use msbuild, I don't see any output on the lines of artifacts or package built.

Comment: Then you don't have the same clone of the repo everybody else has I'm afraid.One last thing I can ask you to try is to right-click the Orchard.Web project and build web deploy packages from there, just to see.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! When I publish/package from Visual Studio, it works fine and create a package. I had downloaded the whole source code just 4 days back!

Comment: And when you do it from a VS command prompt you get no errors, but no artifacts? Did you ever tried build "compile;package"?

Comment: Yes, I did. No Artifacts again.

Comment: I just did it again on a regular clone of the repository, and the artifacts were definitely created. I really have no idea what's wrong with your setup that it doesn't happen. You should at least get some red in the output of that build command.